# SQLite3 Python - Comit() in a later session

Tags: python, sqlite

Pretty simple question with no literature to expound on it here. If you start a connection, then run a job continually for 12 hours inserting data to the .db, if you do not commit and the python script terminates, can you go back in, connect to the database and commit and see the changes?

Comment: nope ... you could have tried it easy enough, once a session is lost all of its uncommitted changes are as well

Comment: Well, well, alrighty then. What about the metadata file that is spawned and gets filled up before the commit is done? Any relationship?

Comment: oh hmmm im not sure... maybe there is a way after all... is it just a list of sql commands? or is it some weird format? ive never heard of that and not looked for it either

Comment: So as you insert data you get an anonymous `your.db-journal`. After you reconnect you do actually lose your progress.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question but way are you don't committing records as you process? Isn't it more efficient to commit say 100,000 records now than try to commit 1,000,000 at once at the end of the process?